# Passing data between ViewController and TabBar children

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an application which has a a TableView. When I press any cell the app goes to the next ViewController. In this viewController I have created a TabBarController by code which has 3 children ViewControllers. So, I want to pass a variable from the TableView to the Children of the TabBar. I can pass the variable to the TabBar, I have watched it with the NSlog function. It is really weird for me that in the children ViewControllers I also have type a NSlog and the variable is null, but in the output I see first this.

```
2013-10-01 03:01:40.687 Prototype[38131:c07] proId (null) // This is the children log from vc2 ViewController  "YPProjectViewController"
2013-10-01 03:01:40.697 Prototype[38131:c07] projectID 433 // This is the TabBar LOG YPTabBarViewController
```

Does somebody know why I can first the Children NSLog? Maybe there is the solution.

```
#import "YPTabBarViewController.h"
#import "YPProjectViewController.h"
#import "YPCommentsViewController.h"
#import "YPProposalsViewController.h"

@interface YPTabBarViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong)UITabBarController *tabBar;
@end

@implementation YPTabBarViewController
@synthesize tabBar;
@synthesize projectId = _projectId;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpTabBar];

}

// Set up tabBar
-(void)setUpTabBar
{

        YPCommentsViewController *vc1 = [[YPCommentsViewController alloc] init];
        vc1.title = @"Comments";
        vc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UINavigationController *contentNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];

        YPProjectViewController *vc2 = [[YPProjectViewController alloc] init];
        vc2.title = @"Project";
        vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        vc2.proId = _projectId;
        NSLog(@"PROJECT ID %@", vc2.proId);
       // UINavigationController *contentNavigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];


        YPProposalsViewController *vc3 = [[YPProposalsViewController alloc] init];
        vc3.title = @"Proposal";
        vc3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UINavigationController *contentNavigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];
        tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        tabBar.viewControllers = @[contentNavigationController,vc2,contentNavigationController3];
        tabBar.selectedIndex   = 1;

        [tabBar.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [tabBar willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self addChildViewController:tabBar];
        [tabBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.view addSubview:tabBar.view];
```

}

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited the question. It is true what you say

Comment: Do you mean this ? `@implementation YPProjectViewController
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;
     NSLog(@"proId ID %@", _proId);
    return self;
}`

Comment: But, I am not looking at it in init, I have done it to show you, I show proId log in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of understanding the problem, your `NSLog` statement in the "tab bar controller" is logging the value of `vc2.proID` immediately after setting it. But your NSLog output show us that that second tab's view controller is logging its results *before* that. That's why it's `nil` when the second tab's view controller's `viewDidLoad` logs it, because that log is happening before the tab bar controller had a chance to set the value and log it itself.

So, there are a couple of ways you could fix this:

1. Right before your assignment of `vc2.proId`, you have an innocuous line of code that says:

   ```
   vc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   ```

   That line of code triggers the second view controller's view to be loaded (and its `viewDidLoad` will be called). If you move the assignment of `vc2.proId` to before you start accessing any of `vc2`'s views, that will change the order that your `NSLog` statements appear (or, much better, move the setting of the background color into `viewDidLoad` of the child controllers).
2. You could just create your own `init` method that accepts the project id as a parameter. That would also ensure that it's set before `viewDidLoad`. Thus, `YPProjectViewController` could have a method such as:

   ```
   - (id)initWithProjectId:(NSString *)projectId
   {
       self = [self init];

       if (self)
       {
           _proId = projectId;
       }

       return self;
   }
   ```

---

Two unrelated observations regarding the custom container calls:

1. When you call `addChildViewController`, it calls `willMoveToParentViewController` for you. So you should remove the call to `willMoveToParentViewController`. See the [documentation for that method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW77).
2. You might even want to retire these custom container calls altogether, and just make `YPTabBarViewController` a subclass of `UITabBarController`, itself, rather than `UIViewController`. That eliminates the need to custom container calls altogether. Clearly, if you have other needs for the custom container, then feel free, but it's redundant in this code sample.

Comment: I was going to say much the same as Rob here. I would add that most of the controller attributes you are setting here, in my opinion, should be handled by the controllers themselves. The title and background color specifically. The didmoves and the willmoves certainly do not belong in here. I will recommend Rob's idea of custom initiator and any other communications between these views should be handled by way of delegate/protocol or NSNotification as appropriate.

Comment: @DeanDavids Agreed. By the way, it's not just a matter of good style, but there are also performance/memory reasons to not have this tab bar controller not try to update the `view` objects of the child controllers. If the tab bar controller accesses each of the child views, it's going to load up all of those views up front. There's no reason to suffer this (modest) hit. If you defer these view updates until `viewDidLoad` of the respective children, their views won't be created until you absolutely need them (e.g. the user taps on that tab). Thus, starts more quickly and consumes less memory.